# How to change home page from Index to something else?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to have a home page different from Index.cshtml

`http(s)://localhost:5000` ==> currently correspond to `http(s)://localhost:5000/Index`

Found on the internet variations around the same concept:

In Startup.Configure changing from this

```
app.UseMvc();
```

to this

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Viewer}");
});
```

By the way: where is the Home controller? Is it implicit?

Comment: Instead of Index view, which view are you trying to make default? Viewer?

Comment: yes. And I'd like the landing page is http(s)://localhost:5000/ === http(s)://localhost:5000/Viewer

Comment: After setting `routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Viewer}");` it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I use .Net core 3.1 and used this in startup file

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", " 
{controller=Home}/{action=Viewer}/{id?}");});
```